# Удалённый хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

Разворачиваю приложение Asp.Net Core в пределах домена. Но с одной из клиентских машин *(Windows7 64bit)* возникла проблема. При попытке вытащить контекст данных

```html
Options = optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
{
  _ = sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(
    maxRetryCount: 5,
    maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
    errorNumbersToAdd: null
  );
}).Options;
```

выбивает следующую ошибку

```
Maximum number of retries (6) exceeded while executing database operations with 'SqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy'. See the inner exception for the most recent failure.
```

До добавления **EnableRetryOnFailure** было такое сообщение:

```
An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. Consider enabling transient error resiliency by adding 'EnableRetryOnFailure()' to the 'UseSqlServer' call.
```

Внутренняя ошибка всегда одна и та же:

**(10054): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)**

База данных, из которой пытаюсь вытянуть контекст - MS SQL Server 2005. Сам сервер с БД пингуется, через .udl файл подключается спокойно, через OdbcConnection все данные подтягиваются, но при попытке создать контекст, или попытке соединения посредством SqlConnection хост прерывает соединение.

На сервере бд при неудачном подключении наблюдается такая картина:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Самое интересное, что это единственная машина, которая не смогла подключиться к базе. Разные версии Windows разной разрядности, все так или иначе работали хорошо. Где-то прочитал, что это может возникнуть из-за непропатченной версии Винды. После этого все обновления проверял, часть снёс, часть поставил. IPv4 настроен как у  всех, IPv6 вообще отключен. Членство в доменных группах как и у других, прокси-сервер такой же. Антивирус отключал. DHE-шифрования успешно отключал, так в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: В тексте ошибки `'UseMySql'` - что-то тут не то.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Спасибо, что заметили. Сейчас исправил вопрос - это был лог не моей ошибки :(

Comment: Не пробовали гуглить код ошибки? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error?view=sql-server-ver16#login-failed-for-user-username-or-login-failed-for-user-domainusername

Comment: И да, имя пользователя вы зря замазали. Скажите хотя бы там пользователь SQL Server или виндовый...

Comment: @PavelMayorov Аутентификация через учётку SQL server. Под этим пользователем бд почти все другие и работают

Comment: @PavelMayorov код ошибки гласит, что пароль неверен. Знаю, что он case-sensetive. Доходило до того, что менял раскладки клавиатуры с американского на британский и наоборот. Потом и вовсе вынес строку подключения в программный код